# Quartz Scheduler Start and Stop from button

Tags: java, swing, quartz-scheduler

I'm trying to create a cronjob application with JAVA.
I'm using the `Quartz Scheduler` plugin. Everything was looking good but i have to find out a way to stop/pause it and then restart it.

I have created a GUI using `Swing` and a system tray with two buttons. Stop and Start. The Start button works fine and starts the scheduler outputting the desired results. However i cannot right click on the icon for the menu to popup on the system tray until the scheduler is shutdown.

Below is the function that starts the Cronjob

```
public static void startCron(String serverAddress, int interval) throws Exception {

        JobDetail job = JobBuilder.newJob(RunCron.class).withIdentity("mainCron", "group1").build();

        // Trigger the job to run on the next round minute
        Trigger trigger = TriggerBuilder
            .newTrigger()
            .withIdentity("dummyTriggerName", "group1")
            .withSchedule(
                SimpleScheduleBuilder.simpleSchedule()
                    .withIntervalInSeconds(interval).repeatForever())
            .build();


        // schedule it
        Scheduler scheduler = new StdSchedulerFactory().getScheduler();
        scheduler.start();
        scheduler.scheduleJob(job, trigger);

        try {
            Thread.sleep(8000);                 //1000 milliseconds is one second.
            scheduler.shutdown();
            System.out.println("System was shut down");
        } catch(InterruptedException ex) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }

    }
```

Cronjob is just an http request to a server and a response.
I have a sleep and shutdown after 8 seconds to prevent never ending execution since the GUI is not responding while the job is running.

Comment: I'm not a quarz expert, but I'd say that `Thread.sleep(8000);` prevents your application from handling any input until the 8 seconds are over.

Comment: you are correct!! I used it to prevent it from running forever! Fairly new to java. Although i keep getting an exception when i try to shut it down

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Thread.sleep(8000);` prevents your application from handling any input until the 8 seconds are over.